# Navigate from one lightning Component to Lightning App builder

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, lightning-app-builder

Can we build a Lightning app builder with different components and save it and redirect a Lightning component to that app builder page.

Scenario - `Since GoogleDoc object record details cannot be viewed in Lightning experience` 
So am building a lightning component with to view the google doc in Lightning Experience,

> Can I build a Highlight panel as a separate component and Records
>   detail as a separate component and use it in a Lightning App builder

Upon clicking the Google Doc record from opportunity redirect to Builder Page.

***Important Question - Can we redirect to lighting app builder page from lightning Component.***

Is it possible?

Comment: You may want to consider using [Component Visibility](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_page_components_visibility.htm&type=5) filters to hide/show different components based on the filters you provide

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with -- *Can we build a Lightning app builder* -- You **cannot** build an app builder, that's a developer/admin tool provided by the platform. Why would you want to redirect to app builder from a component?

Comment: I build a Component that displays all the Google Doc attachments of the Opportunity and included in opportunity page. And now If I click the Google Doc it should take me to the Doc Record `but Google doc records are not visible in lightning (Only classic)` in that case I want to build an app builder page(like other related record's detail page (like Case or any Related)) and redirect to that page once I click the Doc record -- I am not sure if we can create app builder page though to use like that. (New to the builder).  **Can we build a Lightning app builder** --new lightning App builder page